# Error when i try to add cookie to actual driver with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, office365

I'm trying to load the outlook mail cookie from my session to avoid having to log in again, but I get an error message.

I'm storing the cookie in a json file but I can't get it to work, whereas on other sites or in local tests I have no problem!

Here's my code for extracting the cookie once I'm logged in :

```
actualCookie = driver.get_cookies()
with open('outlookCookie.json', 'w', newline='') as outputdata:
    json.dump(actualCookie, outputdata)
```

And to try to load it, here is the code:

```
driver = Driver() 
driver.get('https://login.live.com/')
with open('outlookCookie.json', 'r', newline='') as inputdata:
    cookies = json.load(inputdata)

for cookie in cookies:
    try:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)      
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
driver.get('https://login.live.com/')
```

the error I get when I run the code :
Message: unable to set cookie.